# Xcode4 - Check if translated value is used in project

Tags: search, xcode4, localization, localizable.strings

is it possible to check if a translated value is used in my project.

For example, I want to check automatically if e.g.

```
/* 
Localizable.strings
*/
"THOUSAND"="Thousand";
"VALUE"="value"
...
```

is used somewhere in my project (in the following macro: NSLocalizedString(@"THOUSAND",@"");)?

I can do this by search value after value, but let's say there are 1000 values? So automatically do that would save much time :-D

BR & THX,
mybecks

Comment: I guess you don't want to change your workflow? Instead of searching through Localizable.strings make the code the master by using `NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue`? If that would solve your problem then I propose to look at an old post I wrote many moons ago: http://www.greck.eu/blog/2011/11/27/translating-your-iphone-and-ipad-project/